# Query only latest entry for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The goal of the following query is, to check whether a user has been terminated in the system in time. So there is a table that contains information about the system termination (how and when the user has been terminated) and one with the termination date of the user. Since there are three ways to terminate a user, some users have several termination entries. In the end, I only want to see the latest entry before their termination date if they have been terminated at all. All `Date` fields are INT fields.

Current Query:

```
Select
  B.TerminationApproach,
  B.SystemTerminationDate,
  A.UserName,
  A.LastName,
  A.FirstName,
  A.TerminationDate,
  Case
    When B.SystemTerminationDate <= A.TerminationDate Then 0
    Else 1
  End As EvalCheck
From A
  Left Join B On B.User = A.UserName
```

Current Result:

```
TerminationApproach SystemTerminationDate   TerminationDate UserNAme LastName   FirstName   EvalCheck
No profiles 20180301    20180226    AWALL   Wall    Aaron   1
Locally locked  20181027    20180226    AWALL   Wall    Aaron   1
Deleted 20180301    20180226    AWALL   Wall    Aaron   1
No profiles 20180301    20180301  CBLAIR    Blair   Carlos  0
Locally locked  20181027    20180301    CBLAIR  Blair   Carlos  1
No profiles 20180301    20180301    CBLAIR  Blair   Carlos  0
```

Then there is a third table which contains user activity. I need to map the results of my first query to the user activity, to see whether the user has performed changes after in the system after his termination date. The third table looks like this:

```
UserID Date Activity
AWALL 20180227 Table Change
```

So with my example, the end result of my query should look like this:

```
TerminationApproach SystemTerminationDate   TerminationDate UserNAme LastName   FirstName   EvalCheck ActivityAfterTermination
No profiles 20180301    20180226    AWALL   Wall    Aaron   1   Yes
No profiles 20180301    20180301    CBLAIR  Blair   Carlos  0   No
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Comment: I have updated the question and query, maybe now it makes more sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your query are rather disconnected.  It is not clear what columns represent a user or the date you care about.

But the basic idea is:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by UserId order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This query works, I only had to replace DESC with ASC to get the right date and entry. But I still somehow need to connect this to the user activity - any ideas?

Comment: @SMor Wow.  I would never put "Gordon" and "lazy" in the same hemisphere let alone the same comment.  We all have our dogmas, perhaps you would be better served by looking past the style and at the content.